# How do I show the form based on my checkbox value

Tags: php

Based on the user selection I want to show the form elements. Here the user selects `class1`,`class6`,`engg`. How do I bring the all form element in one common form right know I am having different form and form field for class 1,6.

My questions Are:

- If user select class1 I have list class1 form?
- If User select class2 I have to combine class1 and class6 under one form.
- Like wise user select class1,class2,class6,engg.
- I want to make all the form elments under one form.

My FORM

```
    <form name="frm" method="post">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" required ></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class1">class1
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class6">class6
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class8">class8
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class10">class10
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class12">class12
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="engineering">engineering
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="technology">technology
    </td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

My PHP VALUES

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name    = $_POST['txt'];
        $product = $_POST['chk'];
        print_r($product);
        foreach($product as $k=> $v)
    {
    if($v=="class1")
    {
    ?>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <p>class1
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    if($v=="class1" && $v="class6")
    {
    ?>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <p>class1</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <p>class6</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

I want output like this:

For class1 form:

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<p>class1
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

For class1, class6 form:

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<p>class1</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
<p>class6</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank to edit to my question .now it is easy to everyone I hope I can  get very good answer

Comment: can any one help me please ?I could not move further

Comment: still I am not getting the proper code.stack team help me